# Jack not working unless run as root

Tags: jack

For some reason, jack will not start unless I run it as root. When I start it with `jackd -d alsa`, I get the following output:

```
jackd 0.125.0
Copyright 2001-2009 Paul Davis, Stephane Letz, Jack O'Quinn, Torben Hohn and others.
jackd comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details

could not open driver .so '/usr/lib/jack/jack_net.so': libcelt0.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

JACK compiled with System V SHM support.
cannot lock down memory for jackd (Cannot allocate memory)
loading driver ..
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
JACK: unable to mlock() port buffers: Cannot allocate memory
JACK: unable to mlock() port buffers: Cannot allocate memory
```

My user is a member of the `audio` group. Why might this be happening and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Does the file `/usr/lib/jack/jack_net.so` exist? I would assume so, if root is able to run Jack. If so, what are the permissions on this file?

Comment: @ajgringo619 yes, it exists. Here these are the permissions; 



`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 46712 Apr 10  2020 jack_net.so`

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong file. What about `libcelt0.so.2`? I don;t have that on my Mint 20 system; doesn't even show up in a database search.

Comment: You are correct, that file didn't exist. I installed the `celt` package, and then that file did exist, but I still got the same error from jack, just without the "could not open driver" line.

Comment: The important message is "Cannot allocate memory". For solution(s) see https://askubuntu.com/questions/166126/unable-to-start-jack-cannot-allocate-memory. Maybe adding yourself to group `audio` may already help.